# jQuery replaceWith showing text not element

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following jQuery to replace an input field with a select field.

```
input = $("input[id$='id_var']")[0];
input_class = input.getAttribute("class");
input_id = input.getAttribute("id");
input_name = input.getAttribute("name");
//remove input and replace with a select drop down
input.replaceWith("<select class='"+input_class+"' id='"+input_id+"' name='"+input_name+"'></select>");
```

Which runs when I load the page. But instead of replacing the element with the select html, it just replaces it with the html as text:

```
"<select class='input_class_text' id='input_id_var' name='input_name_text'></select>"
```

So on the page rather than a select you just see

```
<select class='input_class_text' id='input_id_var' name='input_name_text'></select>
```

Snippet of the behavior described above:

```js
input = $("input[id$='id_var']")[0];
input_class = input.getAttribute("class");
input_id = input.getAttribute("id");
input_name = input.getAttribute("name");
//remove input and replace with a select drop down
input.replaceWith("<select class='"+input_class+"' id='"+input_id+"' name='"+input_name+"'></select>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id_var" type="text" />
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling `.replaceWith()` on a DOM element, not on a JQuery object.
Just edit your first line :

```
input = $("input[id$='id_var']");
```

Then adapt your next lines like so :

```
input_class = input.attr("class");
input_id = input.attr("id");
input_name = input.attr("name");
```